# I bought LVT do I need underlayment and a vapor barrier on concrete floor

Tags: flooring

The installer is trying to lay the lvt on an uneven concrete floor. What is the best way to prepare the concrete floor for the LVT?

Comment: The best way to prepare assumes a large budget - is that valid?  Is your LVP water proof or water resistant?  Sometimes the LVP comes with an underlayment built into it, sometimes that underlayment is a vapor barrier.

Comment: I would be more worried about the uneven floor.  Those floors like flat/smooth(not level) floors.  Dips and ridges in the floor not good beginning.

Comment: What does the manufacturer say?

Comment: Have your or your installer read the instructions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's not a smooth finish, the best approach would be self leveling concrete.  If it is smooth, then you'd need to scratch the entire surface with a grinder or similar.  Because concrete is susceptible to moisture wicking up from the ground below, a vapor barrier is generally recommended.  Flooring companies often install a 6 MIL plastic as a vapor barrier underneath LVT.  If you choose to use an underlayment, it should be thin and dense.  A thin foam underlayment made of polyethylene or polypropylene could serve as a dual purpose for both moisture and as cushion for imperfections in the concrete.
Masonite might also make a good choice if used in conjunction with a vapor barrier and could prevent you from having to try to level your concrete depending upon how unlevel it is.

Comment: Who is "they" that recommend the 6 mil plastic? Please [edit] that in to improve your answer.